# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python

```
def prime(x):
    if (x == 0 or x % 2 == 0):
        return 0
    elif (x == 1):  
        return 1
    else:
        for y in range(x-1,0,-1):
            if (x % y == 0):
                return 0
            else:
                pass
        if (y == 1):
            return 1

for x in range(1,20):
    if (prime(x)):
        print ("x:%d, prime YES") % (x)
    else:
        print ("x:%d, prime NO") % (x)
```

I'm starting experimenting Python and I can't understand what's wrong with my code... I'm getting:

> ...    print ("x:%d, prime YES") % (x)
>   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Comment: We need some more information to help you properly.  Are you getting an errors?  If so, what line is causing the error?  Have you tried anything to attempt to rectify it, and if so, what did you try?

Comment: there is a case where the `prime` function returns nothing at all (i.e. will return `None`). And `None` cannot be formatted as an integer.

Comment: The error is in the title BTW..

Comment: But he never tries to output the result of isprime as an integer, so that's no problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Wait -- I've found it. You are using Python 3! In which `print` is a function. And therefore,

```
print ("x:%d, prime YES") % (x)
```

actually means

```
(print ("x:%d, prime YES")) % (x)
```

And since `print` returns `None`, that gives you the error you are getting.

Also, beware -- `(x)` is not a tuple containing 1 element, it's simply the value `x`. Use `(x,)` for the tuple.

So just move the parens and add a comma:

```
print("x:%d, prime YES" % (x,))
```

Comment: That solved my problem! Thanks! Two ither questions: you said that now print is a function... What was "print" in python 2.x? And, is "y" remembered after my for loop in the prime function? Thanks!!!

Comment: `print` used to be a statement, used with parens. Yes after that for loop, `y` will have the last value it had in the loop.

Comment: If you use Python 3k, how about `print("X:{}, prime YES".format(x))` ?