# Basic Python Loop with i and %r substitution

Tags: python

I have a large script I am trying to loop. At a minimal level though, it looks something like this:

```
for i in range (0,7):
    print ("working_loop %r ") % i
```

My expectation is that this will run seven loops, and i will increase and should print "working_loop 0" on the first loop, followed by 1,2,3 ect. on the following iterations.

However, I get the following error

```
unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

I thought perhaps %s or %d would make it work, but I get the same error.

Comment: `print ("working_loop %r " % i)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22070888/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-nonetype-and-int)

Comment: Note that the thing you want to print should go inside the parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is basic syntax error:

Change

```
print ("working_loop %r ") % i
```

to

```
print ("working_loop %r " % i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Marcus has your answer, but optionally, if we're using Python 3.6+, we can use a format template string.

```
print(f'working_loop {i}')
```

Or, you can use the more backward compatible format method as well

```
print('Working_loop {}'.format(i))
# or...
print('Working_loop {index}'.format(index=i))
```